# CountDown Timer With getting Time

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I make a program in Android for Count Down Timer, but I can't stop timer with Stop Button.
And there is another problem. when I Clicked again on the Start Button it crash.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TimerActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText edtNumber;
    public TextView txtCounter;
    public Button   btnStart;

    public Typeface time_font;

    String          num;
    int             get_number=0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timer);

        txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);
        edtNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        time_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "time_font.ttf");
        txtCounter.setTypeface(time_font);


        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                num = edtNumber.getText().toString();
                final int get_number = Integer.parseInt(num);
                txtCounter.setText(get_number + "");


                ThreadTimer counter = new ThreadTimer();
                counter.setSeconds(get_number);
                counter.setTextView(txtCounter);
                counter.start();

            }
        });

        txtCounter.setText(get_number + "");
    }
}
```

**ThreadTimer.java**

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ThreadTimer extends Thread {

    private int      seconds;
    private int      counter;
    private TextView textView;


    public void setSeconds(int value) {
        seconds = value;
        counter = seconds;
    }


    public void setTextView(TextView value) {
        textView = value;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (counter > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            counter--;
            if (textView != null) {
                G.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int min = (int) Math.floor(counter / 60);
                        int sec = counter % 60;

                        String minPrefix = "";
                        if (min < 10) {
                            minPrefix = "0";
                        }

                        String secPrefix = "";
                        if (sec < 10) {
                            secPrefix = "0";
                        }

                        textView.setText(minPrefix + min + ":" + secPrefix + sec);
                    }
                });
            }
            Log.i("LOG", "Counter: " + counter);
        }

        G.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(G.context, "Alarm ! ! !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**G.java**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;


public class G extends Application {

    public static Context context;

    public static final Handler HANDLER = new Handler();


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
}
```

**timer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/layout_background">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" android:hint="Enter Your Time" android:layout_margin="8dip" android:background="@drawable/txt_counter_style"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_weight="0" >


    </LinearLayout>

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:text="Start"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
           android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCounter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="--:--"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="48dip"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better if you reuse the existing Android components that were created especially for this purpose. There's a [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) included with Android that you can use:

```
int countDownLength = 30000; // counts down 30 seconds
int countDownInterval = 1000; // updates the timer every second
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(countDownLength, countDownInterval) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // called when the timer is updated
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // called when the timer has finished
    }
};
timer.start();
// ...
timer.cancel();
```

---

To fix your code there are a few things you should keep in mind:

1. Stopping your timer: in order to properly cancel your timer you need to hold a reference to your runnable and then cancel that runnable using:

   ```
   timer = new Runnable() {...};
   G.HANDLER.removeCallbacks(timer);
   ```

   I'd also recommend that you use a delay for your runnables (for performance reasons, one second delay makes sense here):

   ```
   G.HANDLER.postDelayed(timer, 1000);
   ```
2. Restarting your timer: your code crashes the second time you click your button as the text has changed and cannot be converted to an integer anymore. It's probably best to disable the button while the timer is running using:

   ```
   btnStart.setEnabled(false);
   ```

Comment: if I don't use this, what can I do? Is it Possible to repair my code?

Comment: I'll update my answer with a few hints on how to fix your code. I'd really recomment using the built-in `CountDownTimer` though ;)

Comment: it's true but how can I use Stop Button in this program.This program is important

Comment: Just attach a click listener to your `btnStop` and call either `timer.cancel();` or `G.HANDLER.removeCallbacks(runnable);`, depending on which option you have chosen.

Comment: 1 G.HANDLER.removeCallbacks(runnable); give me error